# Best way to run autonomous process on Linux machine

Tags: linux, fedora

I have a Linux machine that I want to leave unattended. I have a program on this machine that I want to automatically start when the machine boots up and runs unattended.

What is the best way to configure this program to start on startup? I don't have any sort of GUI installed, so can't use gnome-session-properties or anything along that sort of line. Do I have to configure an automatic login to a special autonomous user? If the program can run without having first logged in as a user, what memory can it write to and where can it store text files it needs?

Comment: it would really help to mention which distro you're using. Assuming we start this up with an init script, there are 3 different systems in use today, and the answer will need to take into account of that.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek do you happen to have a link describing the differences between the three and by which distro they are used?

Comment: offhand, no. init.d is the 'old' system. Upstart and startd and alternatives used by ubuntu and fedora respectively. I think the latter can run init scripts, but its very hard to answer without knowing.

Comment: Sorry. Using Fedora.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek surely you meant systemd? In which case I'd advise looking at the archwiki systemd page here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Q:_How_can_I_make_a_script_start_during_the_boot_process.3F

Comment: Precisely! too many darned init replacements. So little time!

Answer (score 0):

For systemd (which is what fedora uses), the [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Q:_How_can_I_make_a_script_start_during_the_boot_process.3F) provides a solution like this:

Create a new file in /etc/systemd/system (e.g. myscript.service) and add the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=My script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/my-script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then

```
# systemctl enable myscript.service
```

This example assumes you want your script to start up when the target multi-user is launched.

Comment: Thanks. Since this process isn't then associated with a user, where can it write/read text files?

Comment: It will be run as superuser if I'm not mistaken. You can have it run as a user by setting uid for it properly I think. That's something you'd have to look up as I've never done it.